# Fourier tranform of the derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform, fourier-restriction

I have been recently studing Fourier transform and there is a proposition that says: If $\lim \limits_{x \to\infty}xf(x)=\lim\limits_{{x}\to -\infty}xf(x)=0$  then $$\hat{f'}(z)=-iz\hat{f}(z)$$

and this is proven like this:

$(f(x)e^{izx})'=f'(x)e^{izx}+izf(x)e^{izx}$

and intergrating by parts we have

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x)e^{izx})'dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)e^{izx}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}izf(x)e^{izx}dx$

or

$f(x)e^{izx}\vert_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty}=\hat{f'}(z)+iz\hat{f}(z)$

But 
$f(x)e^{izx}\vert_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty}=0$ , so we get the desired equality.

My quetion here is why we should  suppose that $\lim\limits_{{x}\to \infty}xf(x)=\lim\limits_{{x}\to -\infty}xf(x)=0$ and not just that $$\lim\limits_{{x}\to \infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{{x}\to -\infty}f(x)=0$$ ? Because then we would have $f(-\infty)e^{iz(-\infty)}=f(\infty)e^{iz(\infty)}=0$

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: See the last half of this answer for a method to avoid integration to prove the theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3088728/441161

Comment: @AndyWalls, Thanks for the refference (+1) but  what I need is to tell me if my statement is correct or wrong not another way to prove it.